# Finding adjacent seating for a train reservation

Tags: java

I have constructed an object train that holds `2 ArrayList<Seating>` for business class and economy class.

My Seating Object has an ArrayList of Seats

```
List<Seating> business_class = new ArrayList<Seating>();
List<Seating> economy_class = new ArrayList<Seating>();
int bCount = 1;
int eCount = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
{
    business_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(bCount), "A"));
    business_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(bCount), "B"));
    business_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(bCount), "C"));
    business_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(bCount), "D"));
    business_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(bCount), "E"));
    business_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(bCount), "F"));

    economy_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(eCount), "A"));
    economy_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(eCount), "B"));
    economy_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(eCount), "C"));
    economy_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(eCount), "D"));
    economy_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(eCount), "E"));
    economy_class.get(i).addSeat(new Seats(Integer.toString(eCount), "F"));
    bCount++;
    eCount++;
}
```

`1A / 1B / 1C || 1D / 1E / 1F`
    `2A / 2B / 2C || 2D / 2E / 2F`

My java program can add either a `single passenger or a group`. For my group reservations, I have to seek the largest amount of available `adjacent seating`. I am stuck on this method. I have coded it already, but it is a mixture and if and else if statements taking into account all the possible combinations of seating. The method has over 600 lines of if-else statements... I am asking for a simpler and more effective way to find adjacent seating for groups.

More detail on adjacent seating 
For example, if all the seats were empty, then I'd have 6 adjacent seats. In the case that I have 6 group members, I would fill the entire row. In the case that I have 7 group members. 1 would be placed in the row before if any available or after if any available starting at (seatNumber)A -> (seatNumber)F 
If there are passengers located at 1A and 1F than I'd have 2 sets of 2 adjacent seats 1B / 1C and 1D / 1E.

In the event that there is a group of 4, then those 4 will fill those seats. In the event that there is a group of 3, then 1B / 1C || 1D will be filled.

That is the logic of this particular adjacent seating method. Business and Economy class have no relationships in seating.

Comment: Search for free space management. That's a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Si i would suggest you to :

create a method `seat.isFree();`which will return `true`if the seat is free and `false`otherwise.

Then iterate each line of seats of your class, and look for the first free `Seat`of your line. It would look like :

```
Seat freeSeat = null;
int length = 0;
for( each line ){
    for( each seat){
        Seat seat = seat.get(indexInLine);
        if(seat.isFree()){
            if(freeSeat == null){
                freeSeat = seat;
                length = 1;
            } else
                length++;
        } else {
            if(freeSeat != null){
                yourList.add(seat, length);
            }
            freeSeat = null;
        }
    }
    if(freeSeat != null){//So if the last seat of the line is also free add it to the free seat list
        yourList.add(seat, length);
    }
}
```

The purpose of your `list` is to contain a list of `Seat` and `int` objects which would represent the first free `Seat` and the number of free seats in the line after it ( including the first one ).

Then you will get every adjacents free seat in your list.

You just have to select the first element of the list whose (int value) length is important for all your group or if none, separate the group while you can't find adjacents seats for them.

Comment: what is the purpose of the line `yourList.add(seat, length)`

Comment: The purpose it to create a list of element containing the first free `Seat` of each line and the number of free seats after him on the line.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. I have a similar code

```
Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);

int count_seat1;

count_seat1=S.nextInt();

int remainder;

remainder=count_seat1%12;

if(remainder==1)
{
    System.out.println( count_seat1+11 +" WS");
}
else if(remainder==2)
{
    System.out.println( count_seat1+9  +" MS");
}
else if(remainder==3)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1+7 +" AS");
}
else if(remainder==4)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1+5  +" AS");
}
else if(remainder==5)
{
    System.out.println( count_seat1+3 +" MS");
}
else if(remainder==6)
{
    System.out.println( count_seat1+1 +" WS");
}

else if(remainder==7)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1-1 +" WS");
}
else if(remainder==8)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1-3+" MS");
}
else if(remainder==9)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1-5+" AS");
}
else if(remainder==10)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1-3+ "AS");
}
else if(remainder==11)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1-9+ " MS");
}
else if(remainder==0)
{
    System.out.println(count_seat1-11+" WS");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).